pass dependencies between GitHub Actions jobs
I have few jobs inside workflows, and every time should install dependencies:
 - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      cd ProjectFolder
      gem install bundler
      bundle install
      pod install

How to avoid this step and do in one time? I read about cache dependencies, and make it:
 - name: Cache bundler dependencies
    uses: actions/cache@v3
    with:
      path: |
        ~/.bundle
        vendor/bundle
      key: bundler-${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('ProjectFolder/Gemfile.lock') }}
      restore-keys: |
        bundler-${{ runner.os }}-
  - name: Cache CocoaPods dependencies
    uses: actions/cache@v3
    with:
      path: |
        Pods
        ~/.cocoapods
        Podfile.lock
      key: pod-${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('ProjectFolder/Podfile.lock') }}
      restore-keys: |
        pod-${{ runner.os }}-
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      cd ProjectFolder
      gem install bundler
      bundle install
      pod install

here is logs from the next job:
Restore Bundler dependencies cache:
  Run actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: ~/.bundle
  vendor/bundle
  
    key: bundler-macOS-2419d82f4e8ef9694cfa939a9a38fcb605e4c89adf5840259fa1bbdef1e22458
    restore-keys: bundler-macOS-
  
    enableCrossOsArchive: false
    fail-on-cache-miss: false
    lookup-only: false
    Received 5176985 of 9371289 (55.2%), 4.9 MBs/sec
    Cache Size: ~9 MB (9371289 B)
    /opt/homebrew/bin/gtar -xf /Users/runner/work/_temp/8bdba8ad-a583-4f02-b9fd-eaa5690f45b4/cache.tzst -P -C /Users/runner/work/ProjectFolder/ProjectFolder --delay-directory-restore --use-compress-program unzstd
    Cache restored successfully
    Cache restored from key: bundler-macOS-2419d82f4e8ef9694cfa939a9a38fcb605e4c89adf5840259fa1bbdef1e22458

      

and Restore CocoaPods dependencies cache:
Run actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: Pods
  ~/.cocoapods
  Podfile.lock
  
    key: pod-macOS-43a71651e7e4d189b535e7e992c1892b3cfb19f33bdef31440fc7d4977943fe6
    restore-keys: pod-macOS-
  
    enableCrossOsArchive: false
    fail-on-cache-miss: false
    lookup-only: false
Cache Size: ~1 MB (887189 B)
/opt/homebrew/bin/gtar -xf /Users/runner/work/_temp/34df416a-8b8b-4312-8981-76071c3aeecb/cache.tzst -P -C /Users/runner/work/ProjectFolder/ProjectFolder --delay-directory-restore --use-compress-program unzstd
Received 887189 of 887189 (100.0%), 0.8 MBs/sec
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: pod-macOS-43a71651e7e4d189b535e7e992c1892b3cfb19f33bdef31440fc7d4977943fe6

But when I started to archive the build, I have error with fastlane and there isn't a lot of gems there:
    Run cd ProjectFolder
  cd ProjectFolder
  bundle exec fastlane build_archive
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/fastlane)
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/definition.rb:605:in `materialize': Could not find fastlane-2.217.0, json-2.7.4, aws-sdk-s3-1.170.0, google-apis-androidpublisher_v3-0.74.0, google-apis-playcustomapp_v1-0.16.0, google-cloud-storage-1.52.0, security-0.1.3, base64-0.2.0, nkf-0.2.0, aws-sdk-core-3.212.0, aws-sdk-kms-1.95.0, google-apis-core-0.15.1, google-apis-iamcredentials_v1-0.22.0, google-apis-storage_v1-0.47.0, googleauth-1.11.2, activesupport-7.2.2, aws-partitions-1.1001.0, mutex_m-0.2.0, rake-13.2.1, google-cloud-env-2.2.1, benchmark-0.3.0, bigdecimal-3.1.8, connection_pool-2.4.1, drb-2.2.1, logger-1.6.1, minitest-5.25.1, securerandom-0.3.1 in locally installed gems (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/definition.rb:201:in `specs'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/definition.rb:268:in `specs_for'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler.rb:164:in `setup'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/setup.rb:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:173:in `with_level'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:119:in `silence'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/setup.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:56:in `require_relative'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:56:in `kernel_load'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:456:in `exec'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:35:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:584:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:29:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/exe/bundle:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.23/exe/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Most popular languages have a dedicated setup action that takes care of caching, for example setup-ruby.

I think the issue is you are not installing the dependencies correctly. There may be other issues, but without the entire Github Actions yaml file it's hard to tell what your other configurations are or what other steps (if any) you are using.
For instance, you must have the actions/setup-ruby@v1 step included in order for your cache to work properly.
Also, actions/cache@v3 is being deprecated in three days (November 30th, 2024). actions/cache@v4 is replacing it and has many speed and performance improvements. Here is an example on how to cache Ruby & Cocoapods dependencies.
Step 1.
To be able to track when your dependencies change, we'll create a custom, composite action in a separate action.yml file which I place in the following path: .github/install-dependencies/action.yml Note that Github recommends that you actually do not use the actions/cache@v3 (or @v4) action for caching Ruby dependencies, but to use actions/setup-ruby@v1 instead.
action.yml file
name: Install dependencies
description: Install and cache Ruby & Cocoapods dependencies 
on: [push, pull_request]
runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    # Manually caching gems isn't trivial and the recommendation is always
    # to rely on this action's bundler-cache options.
    - name: Setup Ruby + Cache Gems
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        # Detects .ruby-version file automatically
        bundler-cache: true

    - name: Cache Pods
      if: runner.os == 'macOS'
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      id: pods-cache
      with:
        path: ./ios/Pods # or .path/to/Pods
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pods-${{ hashFiles('ios/Podfile.lock') }}

    - name: Install pods
      if: runner.os == 'macOS'
      shell: bash
      run: cd ios && bundle exec pod install && cd ..

Step 2.
Next, we will create a workflow to update the cache, since there is no mechanism to do this - usually you just create a new cache and delete the old ones. Set this in the .github/workflows/update-cache.yml path.
name: On Dependency Update
description: Triggers an update to the app's caches when a dependency list changes.

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      # Run only on the default branch
      - "main" # or "master"
    paths:
      # Run only if one of these files have changed
      - "yarn.lock"
      - "ios/Podfile.lock"
      - "Gemfile.lock"
      - ".ruby-version"

jobs:
  rebuild-cache:
    name: Rebuild Cache
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
  
      - name: Rebuild cache
        uses: ./.github/actions/install-dependencies

Step 3.
(optional) Create one last workflow file to read the cache for deployment. Place this in .github/workflows/deploy.yml:
name: Deployment
description: Build and deploy the app stores.

jobs:
  deploy:
    steps:
      - name: Checkout selected branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: ./.github/actions/install-dependencies

        # Build and deploy to App Store and Play Store
        # ...

